# Bluefoot page builder not present when editing content on Schedule New Update

Tags: magento2, upgrade, schedule, bluefootcms

We installed Bluefoot plugin on our Magento 2 website. It provides easy and fast content management for the client, on pages and blocks. But when client want to make content on  "Schedule New Update" modal, there are no Bluefoot button that should enable/disable the plugin.

Is this expected behaviour, and is there any way to make this plugin working with Schedule Update content field?

Magento ver. 2.2.3
Bluefoot ver. 1.0.31

Comment: Please find the below answer, if it is useful for you please mark this as valid answer so this can be use by others if they need.

Answer (score 0):

Enable bluefoot editor for Schedule Update content field.

In your **custom module** in **di.xml** file add below line.

```
<type name="Gene\BlueFoot\Block\Element\Editor">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="supportedModules" xsi:type="array">
          <item name="Magento_Ui" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

More info reference this [answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/225879/how-to-enable-bluefoot-cms-pagebuilder-for-category-and-product-section-in-magen#227529), it will help you to use bluefoot in other area's as well.

Comment: I tried to apply the fix you have shared; everything works ok for cos-pages and sms-blocks, but when trying to adjust things for products (descriptions, short descriptions or details) the information is not saved. Only when saving information in the html format, it would be saved.

Comment: @JulianMurillo i think you are looking same for product page so you need to enable `Magento_Catalog`  for information  see https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/227529/52244, if you are looking something else please provide more information so i can explain more or share the require thing

Comment: I was trying to enable Bluefoot editor for the Schedule Update Content field for cms pages only, but the solution from https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/227529/52244 does not seem to work for me ( I saved it in /vendor/magento/module-catalog/etc/di.xml)

Comment: @JulianMurillo here module sequence is issue because bluefoot is a 3rd party module and you were added bluefoot logic in default code (inside vendor magento...), better to create a custom module and in custom module assign or set *dependency*  with bluefoot module. surely it will work, any help please let me know

Comment: Hi Kanhaiya. Do you have an idea on how such a module should look like? I was not meant to save the changes on the vendor map -since this is not the neat way, just by means of testing-

Comment: @JulianMurillo, your Q -`how such a module should look like` - I guess you are talking about creating a module for this concern. just create basic module and in `module.xml` file add sequence with  `Gene_BlueFoot` and then add a `di.xml` file under `etc` folder of your custom module and `add above given code` then replace `Magento_Ui` with  `Magento_Catalog` then do need full actions like clear cache setup deploy etc and see the changes in admin for product level. you will get bluefoot editer instead of magento default editor. if you feel it match you expectation please vote the answer.

Comment: This modification will not enable BlueFoot to work with content staging, the way BlueFoot stores its content will automatically overwrite the main entities data. Magento Page Builder fully supports content staging.

Comment: @Dave fully agree, but request asked for magento 2.2.x version so giving a patch (or kind of solution), and I hope you will be agree Magento Page Builder for magento 2.3.x version not for 2.2.x.

Comment: @Kanhaiya I totally agree with you, just letting you know the complications of doing such a change! (P.s. I’m the original author of BlueFoot)