# how to enable bluefoot cms pagebuilder for category and product section in magento 2

Tags: magento-enterprise, catalog, magento-2.2.1, magento-ee, bluefootcms

Magento default provide bluefoot cms enable option for CMS block & CMS page.

Need to enable bluefootcms editor in category and product level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After Dig Into Bluefoot Module

I found the solution for enable bluefoot editor for wysiwyg editor

**[Create a custom module](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/build/build.html) or can use [magento minimal sample module](https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples/tree/master/sample-module-minimal)** 
 or use any existing custom module
In this module in `etc` folder

add **[di.xml](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/build/di-xml-file.html)** file and then add below code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Gene\BlueFoot\Block\Element\Editor">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="supportedModules" xsi:type="array">
              <item name="Magento_Catalog" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>    
</config>
```

If you already have **di.xml** file in `etc` folder of your custom module then add below code in `di.xml` file

```
<type name="Gene\BlueFoot\Block\Element\Editor">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="supportedModules" xsi:type="array">
          <item name="Magento_Catalog" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

In bluefoot block `supportedModules` argument working like a layer so if need to add **bluefoot editor** on any **specific module** then pass the module name as an `item` under `supportedModules`

```
<item name="[MODULE_NAME]" xsi:type="string">[MODULE_NAME]</item>
```

My current need for  **Category** and **Product** and both below to **Magento_Catalog** so i added `Magento_Catalog` in item and got editor as per my expectation :).